# What is the fastest way to count each combo from list of lists like a Counter?

Tags: python, list, counter

I have a huge list of over 200.000 of lists inside.
Like this:

```
huge_list = [
    [23, 18, 19, 36, 42],
    [22, 18, 19, 36, 39],
    [21, 18, 19, 37, 42]
]
```

It has the following properties:

1. each number inside each list is unique;
2. each list has its numbers sorted; ***// in this case  it is not,
   JUST for the example purpose.***
3. each number from each list is a random value between 1 and 80;
4. each list has a predefined size of 20 items. Not less, not more.
5. numbers are not every time at the same position inside the list. it
   can be [1,2,3] or [1, 3, 5] but have in common 1, 3 and (1,3).

I want the result to be how many time each combination can be found along all lists:

```
 18:3(times),
 19:3(times), 
 36:2(times), 
(18,42):2(times), 
(19,42):2(times), 
(18, 36):2(times), 
(19, 36):2(times), 
(18,19):2(times), 
(18,19,36):2(times), 
(18, 19, 42):2(times) etc.
```

The slowest and impossible way is to generate all combinations by 1 taken from 80, then by 2 taken from 80, then by 3 taken from 80 and so on until to the combination by 20 taken by 80 which is almost an infinite number. This is impossible to do but also it is impossible by the number of lists inside the huge_list is over 200.000.

I need something like a Counter but faster. As fast as possible please because it will become a lot slower starting from combos of 12 taken by 80 or even less.

This is what I tried to do until now:

```
mydict = {}
while len(huge_list) > 1:
    to_check = huge_list[0]
    del huge_list[0]
    for draw in huge_list:
        for num in to_check:
            # one:
            if num in draw:
                if num in mydict:
                    mydict[num] += 1
                else:
                    mydict[num] = 1
    if 1 in mydict.values():
        for key in mydict.keys():
            if mydict[key] == 1:
                mydict[key] += 1

print mydict
```

Result:

```
{18: 3, 19: 3, 36: 2, 42: 2}
```

But is almost working for just combinations of 1 taken from 80. How to do it for the other combinations? And how to do it faster than this way?

P.S. I need only combination that they have in common, I am not interested in combinations with 1 or 0 match across all the lists. So, maybe, this could help you in speed it to be even faster.

Comment: Consider to use threads or multiprocessing to calculate it at same time in 4(for example) lists at same time. Its same operation with multiple data

Comment: Yes but it doesn't help me finding any combination of 15 or 18 numbers taken from 80 which is repeating across all lists.

Comment: *// in this case it is not, JUST for the example purpose.* So write an example which *does* meet the requirements for your own problem. The purpose of writing a [mcve] is to describe the problem, and so that people can test possible solutions; if your example *isn't* a valid input then it doesn't describe your problem accurately and can't be used as a test case.

Comment: It's also not clear why your output doesn't include combinations like `22, 18, 19, 36 (1 time)`; writing `etc.` here doesn't help explain your problem because only you know what the rest of the output should be. If the output is too long to reasonably include in the question, then make your example smaller so that you can include the whole example.

Comment: "P.S. I need only combination that they have in common, I am not interested in combinations with 1 or 0 match across all the lists. So, maybe, this could help you in speed it to be even faster."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`powerset`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#powerset) algorithm found in `more_itertools` and put them into a `collections.Counter`

```
from more_itertools import powerset
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

huge_list = [
    [23, 18, 19, 36, 42],
    [22, 18, 19, 36, 39],
    [21, 18, 19, 37, 42]
]

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(map(powerset, huge_list)))

print({k if len(k) > 1 else k[0]: v for k, v in c.items() if v > 1 and k})
```

---

**Results**

```
{18: 3, 19: 3, 36: 2, 42: 2, (18, 19): 3, (18, 36): 2, (18, 42): 2, (19, 36): 2, (19, 42): 2, (18, 19, 36): 2, (18, 19, 42): 2}
```

This can probably be sped up using pandas although this seems the most efficient way to do this without pandas

**P.S:** `powerset` is also a part of the [`itertools Recipies`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Comment: True, maybe substrings was the wrong function but the premise is there. I'll look for a more appropriate function.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'd prefer `chain.from_iterable(map(...` over `chain(*map(...`

Comment: It's probably more efficient that way yes, I'll edit/